# Format output with three decimal points

Tags: java, html

Alright, I've been making a table that allows the user to enter certain input and acts like excel. Since this has nothing to do with the purpose of the program and more of how it displays things, I won't discuss its purpose in this post. Is there a way to add more decimal points to the demo output? I have tried adding **'total.toFixed(3)** That didn't solve the issue. Then I tried what I have inserted now. I am out of ideas.

```js
import java.text.NumberFormat;

private static NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
var rate = .00125;
var x = myFunction(.04375, rate); 
function myFunction(a, b) {
    return a + b;   
}   
var total = x*100; 
percent = new DecimalFormat("0.000#%"); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = percent.format(total);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<style>
th{ 
 font-family: Arial Narrow;
 background: #D6D6D6;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 28px;
}

table, th, td{
 border-color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row2 {
 font-family: Arial Narrow;
 font-size: 28px;
}

td {
 
</style>
<html>
<head>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="9" >FANNIE MAE MANDATORY</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">30</td>
 <td colspan="2">20</td>
 <td colspan="2">15</td>
 <td colspan="2">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
 <td></td>
    <td>1 PT</td>
    <td>0 PT</td>
 <td>1 PT</td>
 <td>0 PT</td>
 <td>1 PT</td>
 <td>0 PT</td>
 <td>1 PT</td>
 <td>0 PT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
 <td>$35,000 - $99,999</td>
    <td><p id="demo"></p></td>
    <td id="c7"></td>
 <td id="d7"></td>
 <td id="e7"></td>
 <td id="f7"></td>
 <td id="g7"></td>
 <td id="h7"></td>
 <td id="i7"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Crubright looks like the code snippet cannot be run here. Is this the issue you have?

Comment: Hmmm. No. Whenever I uploaded the code, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use a floating point with `String.format`

```
String.format("%.3f", number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using string format by mentioning the type of decimals you need such as #xxx.xx it restricts the decimal of 2 based on rounding strategy